# Dell EMC ecs object client 3.4.5 setbucketpolicy displays invalid json error

Tags: amazon-s3, emc

Am trying to apply S3 bucket policy using EMC ecs sdk object client version

It works with same code for object client previous version 3.1.3 but doesn't work for latest version 3.4.5 object client version

When I went through the documentation, it was mentioned that v3.4.2 was introduced with some enhancement in principal due to which am getting invalid json error

Comment: Amazon-ECS is a docker container orchestration tool. It is completely unrelated to Dell EMC ECS.